# sqlite3.OperationalError: near " ": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

Hi all right with you? I hope so, so I'm developing a commercial application, however this is giving an error in sql where it speaks:
**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "José": syntax error** as if there was an error in the blank space of the phrase

```
cursor.execute(f"""update funcionarios
            set nome = {nome}, senha = {senha}, telefone = {telefone},
                endereco = {endereco}, anotacoes = {anotacao}
            where cpf = {pesq}
            """)
```

Name "ErlonJunior" without spaces works, but "José Street" with space returns this error:

[image: (IMAGE) Name "ErlonJunior" without spaces works, but "José Street" with space returns this error]

Error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "José": syntax error:

[image: (IMAGE) Error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "José": syntax error]

Comment: Is `senha = {senha}` string interpolation in Python? If yes then  you will get something like   `UPDATE tab SET col = Rua Jose` obvious error because you really want `UPDATE tab set col = 'Rua Jose'`. I suggest to use parametrized query to avoid possible SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda The parameter is as string, is giving error is in the spacing of the string, I already checked the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't format your SQL string by hand (in your case with f-strings), it's error prone. You could use parameterized queries in SQLite3:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as con:

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE funcionarios (id integer PRIMARY KEY, nome text)')

    cur.execute('INSERT INTO funcionarios (nome) VALUES (:nome)',
      {'nome': 'Rua Jose'})

    cur.execute('UPDATE funcionarios SET nome = :nome WHERE id = 1',
      {'nome': 'Santa Maria'})

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM funcionarios')
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

This prints:

```
[(1, 'Santa Maria')]
```

Comment: The problem is when I update, formatted in several ways, and continues the error, the problem is that in the update it is not accepting "white space" between the strings

Comment: @ErlonDantas You can use named parameters in any query. I updated my answer to use UPDATE command with named parameter.

Comment: It worked, oh SQL god @Andrej Kesely
Dude, thank you very much, I tried a lot to solve this, thank you very much